# dhcpd or dhclient not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, dhcp, ipv4

I'm working on a custom Ubuntu 20.04 server and am trying to get a dhcp IP for it. The server has so far run on a static IP and when I run dhcp or dhclient it says `dhcpd: command not found` and `dhclient: command not found`.

The `/sbin` has no dhcpd or dhclient directories but there is a `/etc/dhcp` folder which contains `dhclient-enter-hooks.d`  `dhclient-exit-hooks.d` with scripts in it to which I assume is start/stop dhcp.

What I want to know is if it's possible that dhcp or dhclient is not installed in this machine or if I'm missing the installation path and if it isn't which should be the best one to install to get a dhcp IP from.

Comment: It's possible that it just wasn't installed by those who set up the machine originally. If they are still available you might ask them. If not, you might want to ask the package system whether those packages are installed. It will certainly know better than anyone else. On top of that, it will be super helpful in installing the packages if indeed they aren't installed yet.

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner checked in installed packages, doesn't look like they're installed.

Comment: @BlockchainOffice, ther is no interfaces file only `if-pre-up.d` and `if-up.d` folders there

Comment: Do you got /etc/netplan/FILENAME.yaml ?

Comment: @BlockchainOffice haven't got a netplan folder either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you receive `command not found` when trying to run `dhcp` or `dhclient`, it's possible that these are not installed.

To install the DHCP client utilities run:

`sudo apt install isc-dhcp-client`

This will install the `isc-dhcp-client` package, which includes the dhclient.

After the installation, you should be able to use the `dhclient` command to receive an IP address from a DHCP server.

Make sure that `/etc/network/interfaces` is configured to use DHCP.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Replace `eth0` with your network interface name on your system.

Restart the networking with:

`systemctl restart networking`

You can run the following command to request an IP address:

`sudo dhclient`

The `dhcpd` command you mentioned is for the DHCP server, not the client.

If you need to configure and run a DHCP server, you will need to install and set up the `isc-dhcp-server` package instead.

**Configure network with netplan:**

[How to Configure Networking in Ubuntu 20.04 with NetPlan](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-networking-in-ubuntu-20-04-with-netplan/)

Locate the `netplan` configuration file in the `/etc/netplan/` folder
and has a `.yaml` extension.

Edit the file, should see a `yaml` structure defining the network interfaces and their configurations. Set the `dhcp4` property to `true`.

`nano /etc/netplan/YOUR_NETPLAN_CONFIG_FILE.yaml`

dhcp example:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
```

If you have multiple network interfaces, you can add similar sections for each interface.

Apply changes:

`netplan apply`

Request an IP address:

`sudo dhclient`

**Ubuntu source:**

[Ubuntu Network configuration](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration)

Comment: thanks, didn't know that dhcpd was for the server